# $CIRCLE_SHA1 in CircleCi shows "an unknown revision"

Tags: git, circleci

I am using `$CIRCLE_SHA1` to get the git revision number for a particular build. But the it shows `"an unknown revision"` instead of a git revision `SHA hash`. It runs fine in a production environment and happens when i run it locally. Any help on what I am missing here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This could be similar [to this issue](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/compatibility-with-phabricator/183)

> CircleCI does not `git fetch --tags`, and does not fetch the tag explicitly when building a tag. **It does resolve the tag, but never actually downloads the corresponding commit**. This means that tags and other refs which are not ancestors of a branch head (which is to say: everything in the staging area) are not buildable.

So try first a `git fetch --tags`, or double check the [building a tag paramters](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/api/#new-build).